# Does the safaridriver support proxy configuration?

Tags: selenium, robotframework, safaridriver

I've been trying to use Robot Framework to write some cross browser tests.

One of the requirements is that i need to use a proxy to access the website I am testing. Right now, I am trying to launch the safari browser and get it to go through the proxy to reach the website, but I seem to have an issue.

Here is the Robot framework keyword

```
# ${MY_PROXY} is a variable located elsewhere in the file

Open Safari
    ${desired_capabilities} =    Evaluate    selenium.webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.SAFARI   
 sys, selenium.webdriver
    ${safari_proxy} =    Create Dictionary    proxyType    MANUAL    httpProxy    ${MY_PROXY}  
  sslProxy    ${MY_PROXY}
    Set To Dictionary    ${desired_capabilities}    proxy    ${safari_proxy}
    Create Webdriver    Safari    desired_capabilities=${desired_capabilities}
```

So far, i've been receiving this error
`SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Capability 'proxy' could not be honored.`

Currently using `robotframework-seleniumlibrary 4.5.0` with `selenium 3.141.0`

Does the safari webdriver allow proxies? I can't seem to find much on this topic

Comment: I am also wondering about this. I have found https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5051 but nothing has happened there in four years. Any workarounds (execute an Applescript, or something like that, that sets the proxies from the GUI)?